# Android SecurityException with entry in Manifest

Tags: android, permissions

I'm doing a Gdata Blogger from Android device:

```
GoogleLoginServiceHelper.getCredentials(this, REQUEST_CODE_LOGIN, null,
          GoogleLoginServiceConstants.REQUIRE_GOOGLE,
          BLOGGER_SERVICE, true);
```

I have this permissions in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH"/>   
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.blogger"/>
```

But I got a SecurityException:

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(20985): java.lang.SecurityException: caller pid 20985 uid 10044 lacks com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.BLOGGER

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are permissions perhaps case-sensitive? i.e. "blogger" vs "BLOGGER"

Answer (score 1):

Neither `GoogleLoginServiceHelper` nor those permissions are part of the Android SDK, at least as of Android 2.1.

Comment: This is exactly right, check this out for list of valid permissions: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html You're using a class that is not part of the Android java classes and permissions that Android doesn't implement.